# How to get the IP address from the proxy name?

Tags: proxy

When I open the browser, it jumps out a inputbox with this string:

```
moz-proxy://partnerproxy.xxx.co.jp:86
```

I think this is a proxy server name, but how to get the IP address from this?

Answer (score 2):

Open command prompt and type:

```
ping partnerproxy.xxx.co.jp
```